# Parsing text file to variables

Tags: bash

```
$ cat file.txt
example1@domain1-username
```

I'd like to parse `file.txt` and export the contents to variables like:

```
var1=example1@domain1
var2=username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var1=$(cut -d "-" -f 1 file.txt)

var2=$(cut -d "-" -f 2 file.txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using just Bash builtins:

```
$ IFS=- read var1 var2 <<< "$(< file.txt)"    
$ declare -p var1 var2                      
declare -- var1="example1@domain1"                        
declare -- var2="username"
```

This sets the field separator `IFS` to `-`, then reads the file into the two variables.

`<<< "$(< file.txt)"` is a but unwieldy, as we're treating the file just like the single line of text that it is.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will set var1 and var2 in a single pass over file.txt:

```
. file.txt
```

Comment: I think the second example is what OP wants, not what they have.